# Tomcat unable to start application

Tags: spring, tomcat, web-applications

I have installed `petclinic` application in `tomcat` server. During `tomcat` start up and loading of `petclinic` application I am having the error with the followed stack trace. How to resolve this issue ?

> apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/petclinic
>       Oct 27, 2016 12:14:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
>
> SEVERE: Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
>      javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class  at
>   org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5423)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1120)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1678)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:483)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:274)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:798) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig    at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:94)     at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:169)    at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1781)  at
>   org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:157)
>     ... 12 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
>     ... 18 more

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't let spring know about some bean class.

Look at your context.xml or dispatcher-context.xml.

In the exception stack above,
it says java.lang.ClassNotFoundException occured.

Spring can't find class files even if you have them in your java src package.

If my answer doesn't solve your problem,
you need to show your xml or source code to make sure what the problem is.

Comment: i have the context.xml empty , like plain tomcat installation context.xml , and in the petclinic application there is no dispatcher-context.ml also